# Возможность декларации условий в Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Уважаемые знатоки MS SQL, подскажите пожалуйста про возможность декларации условий, как указано в примере ниже:

есть код вида:

```
select * from table where cond1=111 and cond222=222 and cond3=333
union all
select * from table where cond1=111 and cond222=222 and cond4=444
union all
select * from table where cond1=111 and cond222=222 and cond5=555
```

Есть ли возможность как то задекларировать повторяющееся условие в Microsoft SQL, чтобы получилось что-то вроде такого:

```
DECLARE @MyCondition AS varchar = 'cond1=111 and cond222=222

select * from table where @MyCondition and cond3=333
union all
select * from table where @MyCondition and cond4=444
union all
select * from table where @MyCondition and cond5=555
```

Comment: А просто `select * from table where cond1=111 and cond222=222 and cond3 IN (333,444,555)` - не наш метод?

Comment: Вопрос больше в том, что есть большой код на SQL, и для удобства бы хотелось одно длинное условие декларировать в какой то переменной. И это условие будет использоваться в коде несколько десятков раз. А хотелось бы поменять это условие просто один раз в какой то переменной в начале кода. cond3 в моем случае число для примера, и может представлять собой постоянно разные условия cond3, cond4, cond5 и т.д. Спасибо, я уточнил вопрос.

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум - функция. Ей параметры, она результат, который  сверяем с эталонным при выполнении набора условий.